# using which IPC I can pass file descriptor from one process to another on same machine?

Tags: c, unix, filesystems, ipc

I want to pass Unix file descriptor from one local (same machine processes) process to another process. Which are the IPCs mechanism useful from below?

```
PIPE/FIFO/Message Queue/ Shared Memory/ Socket / TLI / stream/ RPC**
```

Comment: [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way of passing a file descriptor from one process to the other is using Unix domain sockets, via the ancillary data of `sendmsg` and `recvmsg`.