# Pass socket descriptor to other process on Linux using Mono

Tags: linux, mono

I need to pass a socket descriptor to another process on Linux using Mono.  On Windows this is easily accomplished using Socket.DuplicateAndClose(int).  I have found this post describing the process in c:

[Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

In my program I have been able to create Unix sockets between two Mono programs using Mono.Unix and Mono.Unix.Native namespaces.  I have been able to find some details that are roughly similar here:

http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/lib/csharp/MonoExample/NDesk-dbus/

I am still getting an EINVAL error when I try to send a socket descriptor.  Does someone have a sample of this working?

Comment: Can you show the code you have for the sockets so far? This shouldn't be too hard: you just need to use the `sendmsg(2)` and `recvmsg(2)` functions to pass around the socket descriptor to the other processes. You're doing this in Linux/UNIX, right?