# Sharing file descriptor table with child after child has done an exec

Tags: c, linux, fork

Is there any way to create a new process which shares your file descriptor table even after an exec? `clone(CLONE_FILES)` won't work, as the man page says:

> If a process sharing a file descriptor table calls execve(2), its file descriptor table is duplicated (unshared).

Comment: What's the goal here? Why would you want a live, shared copy of the file descriptor table once the processes stop even being the same executable? It seems nonsensical at first glance, so I'm suspicious this may be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm writing an x86 user mode emulator for Linux and testing it by running a real process under ptrace at the same time as the emulator and comparing the cpu state at each instruction. When it's time to emulate an mmap call, I want to take the FD used in the parent and overwrite edi to use it in the child. Not a very common use case, that's for sure.

Comment: Even though the open file descriptors are not shared after the `execve()`, the open file descriptions are still shared — yes, there really are descriptors and descriptions.  Read the POSIX specifications of [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html),
[`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html),
[`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) carefully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm talking about the descriptors, not the descriptions. I want an `open` in the parent process to change the file descriptor table of the child process.

Comment: Nothing doing, then — can't be done using POSIX system calls.  If you want that level of sharing, you should be using threads instead of processes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't care about POSIX, I just want it to work on Linux

Comment: Then you'll have to wait for someone else to tell whether it can be done, but I'd be moderately surprised if it can.  I'm not convinced I can see a use case for it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm getting the feeling I'm the only one in the world who actually wants to do this...

Comment: @tbodt You probably are the only person who wants to do it, and for some reason some people will assume that makes you an idiot.

Comment: @immibis I've described the root problem I'm trying to solve in the second comment, if anyone has any better ideas I'd be glad to hear them

Comment: @immibis and idiots are so happy when they find each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by injecting into the child process a custom piece of code responsible for the receival of FDs and updating the child's descriptor table.

Child process should create AF_UNIX socket and recvmsg() on it, while parent process should duplicate and "stream down" the required file descriptors using sendmsg() - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing