# Send socket through Unix pipe

Tags: sockets, unix, pipe

I have a listener which spawns a child each time he accepts() a connection.
I'd like the children to then manage their socket on their own. Since I can communicate with the children through pipes, I'd like to know if I can send the socket through it.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You cannot use a pipe but a socket to transfer a file descriptor. See [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

Comment: Apart from that - if you fork the children anyway after the accept it will already inherit the fd - thus no need to transfer it through a pipe or similar.

Comment: OK thank you. The thing is I'm not forking, but spawning. I know the children can inherit the fd even with a spawn(), but I don't get how to use this inheritance. I'm spawning another program, so the code and variables are not the same.
So how should I declare the fd in the child ? Should it be a parameter or just a local variable ?
Anyway, I think I'll stick to the socket to transfer the fd, it was my first idea anyway.