# Passing a file descriptor to another process in Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-descriptor, unix-socket

I've read that you can pass a file descriptor to another process [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358843/962828), which seems perfect for what I want. Any chance that's do-able in Haskell in any way ?
To be clear, I'm not forking and I can't pre-open the file, I actually need a way to pass a file descriptor (mainly stdin) from a bunch of processes to a daemon, to avoid having to keep processes up just to forward their input, that'd fill the process list quite fast and would probably eat ressources for no reason.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file descriptor of STDIN from the [unix package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-IO-ByteString.html#v:stdInput) and UNIX-domain sockets from [network](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.0.1.0/docs/Network-Socket.html#g:18).

I've never tried passing a file descriptor between processes, but it should work the same in Haskell as any other language.

Comment: Oh I was looking at the deprecated sendAncillary functions, I didn't even realize there's a sendFd and RecvFd .. Thanks, I'll try it out !

Comment: I didn't read far enough down the page to find `sendFd`!  Good to know. :)