# Is it possible to deploy without downtime without disconnecting TCP sockets connected?

Tags: sockets

There is a long connected TCP socket. Up to two clients can connect to a server. In other words, the load is not high. However, once a TCP connection is made, the socket will not be disconnected unless there is an accident, such as a server power down or network failure. Is it possible to reuse an existing TCP socket when restarting the process? I think TCP load balancer like AWS NLB cannot be used since the existing socket won't be moved to a new application. I'd like to have a deployment without downtime, as the system i'm working on is a system that can suffer financial damage when a socket is broken and data is lost. Low-level socket programming is ok.

I have read CloudFlare's https://blog.cloudflare.com/graceful-upgrades-in-go/ article explaining Nginx's Gracefully Reload mechanism. Since an HTTP server is a server that opens and closes sockets frequently, that article assumes that the server's connection would someday be closed, but my situation is slightly different. So I'm not sure if this can be used.

Comment: And there's probably no way that you can replace this broken by design protocol?

Comment: Haha.. when they are disconnected, they connect to each other again. I'm afraid it can only be lost when the TCP connection is lost. Of course, it is best to change to a protocol that terminates after request-response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket can be shared between multiple processes, for example by opening the socket in same parent processing and forking a child process. But if the last process using the socket is closed the socket and thus the underlying connection is implicitly closed.

This means you must make sure that there is always a process open which uses the socket. This can be for example done if the deployment of the new software does not first exit the old process and then creates the new one but if the new process would start and the old process would transfer the socket to the new one, see [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)
 for how this can be done in Linux. Other ways would be using file descriptor inheritance when doing a `fork()`.

Note that these sharing of file descriptors will only work with plain sockets where the state is fully kept in the OS kernel. It will be much harder or impossible with TLS sockets since in this case also the current user space state somehow needs to be shared.

Another way is to have some intermediate "proxy" which on the hand has the stable socket connection to your fragil application and on the other hand is a robust socket handling (i.e. reconnect when needed) to the application you want to update. Then this proxy transfers the traffic between both sides and will reconnect the socket if needed whenever a problem occurs.