# How to forward a socket connection in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server

Provided having two separate **server applications**: e.g. *ServerAppAlpha* and *ServerAppBeta*, one of them (*ServerAppAlpha*) shall receive **socket connections** from clients:

```
# ServerAppAlpha

import socket

svr = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
svr.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9090))
svr.listen(5)

while (True):
    conn, addr = svr.accept() 
    from_clnt = svt.recv(4096)
    # conn == <socket.socket fd=552, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9090), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 53006)>

    svr2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    svr2.connect(('127.0.0.2', 9090))
    # somehow forward both "conn" and "from_clnt" to ServerAppBeta"
```

and forward both `conn` and `from_clnt` to the other one (*ServerAppBeta*), so that it could directly respond to the client:

```
# ServerAppBeta

import socket

svr = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
svr.bind(('127.0.0.2', 9090))
svr.listen(5)

while (True):
    conn, addr = svr.accept()
    from_alpha = svr.recv(4096)
    # somehow send something to the client, who sent a request to ServerAppAlpha
```

Furthermore, the **client application** is something like this:

```
# ClientApp

import socket

clnt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clnt.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9090))
clnt.send('SampleRequest'.encode()) # Sends to ServerAppAlpha
clnt.recv(4096) # Receives from ServerAppBeta
```

The primary goal is to have a transparent distributed system, so that the client “feels” dealing with a single server. So the questions are:

1. How to forward a connection from one server to another?
2. How can a client send a request to one server and receive the response from another?

Comment: You cannot forward a *"connection"*. You can only forward the data by reading from one side and writing what what you've read to the other side, and then do this for both directions.

Comment: So would there be a way to create an object from `<class 'socket.socket'>` on _ServerAppBeta_ and somehow fill up the args using e.g. `<socket.socket fd=552, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9090), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 53006)>`  (the client `conn` which was converted into a string), so that it could directly connect and respond to the client?

Comment: No, this would not be possible. The client would not expect any data from ServerAppBeta on this port, i.e. the connection attempt would fail.

Comment: If your ServerAppBeta is running on the same system, you could just have your ServerAppAlpha call ServerAppBeta with a socket descriptor, then initialize the socket from that descriptor. Not sure if that will work in windows though. Otherwise, you can just open a thread or process using the multiprocessing or multithreading modules, and pass the socket object as argument. Though I have to admit, I have only tested this with threads.
But this won't do you much good if you have multiple systems.

Comment: On a unix (or linux) system, it is possible to pass the socket file descriptor to another process through Unix domain sockets. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358843/1076479. I have never seen it done in a python program, but there is no reason why it couldn't be. It will be tedious to implement and probably require the use of `ctypes` module, but it's possible.