# How to use a existing established TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, file-descriptor

I wanted to use a already established TCP connection to send request and receive response

`tcp4       0      0  192.168.58.72.50913    17.248.162.6.https     ESTABLISHED`

as you can see above, a tcp connection is already in established state, this connection is created by some other process. I being a root user wanted to use the same connection to send request and receive response. is this possible. ??? if yes, can you please tell how to do it ?

Comment: You can't. The socket endpoint is owned by that other process and does not work outside it. And in any case you will never be able to successfully multiplex either a TLS or an HTTP connection let alone an HTTPS connection. Why do you think you want to do this? What's the problem with creating your own connection?

Comment: hmm okay,
then how does connection poolers work ??? 
my assumptions was connection poolers holds few established connections and hands over to the process which requests for a connection and claims it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to **SHARE** the connection (or FD, file descriptor) between the existing process -- that's quite dirty and not recommended.

Although there's a way to pass FD between processes (see this: [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)), it needs target process to send its FD to you (rather than fetch the FD by yourself).