# MySQL Error mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to run a PHP Script that contains a MySQL connection, when I run the command I get the following error in the terminal:

```
'Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused'
```

Even with PDO, I get the error:

```
'Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in ...'
```

I'm running the script on Mac OS X, and I have MAMP as APACHE/MySQL local server.

The command that I use for running the script is:

'php main.php'

and the content of the 'main.php' file with PDO is:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',root,root);
```

with mysqli connector:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "root", "root");
```

I tried with '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' and I get the same errors in both cases.

Comment: Possible solution for you: [PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905297)

Comment: And are you able to connect to MySql using a shell or another client?

Comment: Yes of course, I'm able to access to mysql using shell, I tested it, the problem is when I'm trying to run the script using php command

Answer (score -1):

First of all, using `localhost` as a domain name is [not supported in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php). It will **not** be resolved as `127.0.0.1`.

Second, even using `127.0.0.1` might not work in servers with multiple interfaces or with special routing rules. Run `mysqlcheck --help` and take the IP address shown at the bottom in the "host" field. For example:

```
port                              3306
host                              192.168.1.23
```

Use the IP and port that MySQL recognizes:

```
$db = new mysqli("192.168.1.23:3306", "test", "root", "root");
```

Comment: Can you share more details about that statement "It will not be resolved"? I think the documentation is inconsistent, as https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php uses `localhost`, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp does that too

Comment: ...additionally, the link you've provided shows successfully started MySQL connections both for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

Comment: As I posted in the link "not supported in PHP" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), the PHP documentation itself mentions explicitly (second paragraph): "The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead. "

Comment: Yeah, as written there: "it is not possible to open a **TCP/IP connection**" - using sockets, this works fine. Additionally, using sockets is faster as you skip the network overhead (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838358 for this)